# systemctl start foo.timer also starts foo.service even though the OnCalendar criteria hasn't been met

Tags: systemd, services, systemctl, systemd-timer

So I have my service unit (runs some node code) and my timer unit
Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=foo

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/services/foo/start.sh
```

Timer

```
[Unit]
Description=foo timer 

[Timer]
OnBootSec=0min
OnCalendar=*-*-* 05:01:00 UTC 
Unit=foo.service 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I understand that `systemctl start foo.timer` , will start the timer unit but not the service unit immediately (without reboot) and `systemctl enable foo.timer`  will not start the timer unit but start it when the system boots up.

I wanted to start the timer immediatey so I used the former. It did start the timer but it also started my `foo.service` as I started the timer even though the `OnCalendar` conditions were not met. It still started correctly at the `OnCalendar` time, too (I was testing so I chose a time in the near future).

I'm wondering if there is anything in my unit file causing this. I thought that starting the timer would not start the service but only start the service when the condition is fulfilled in the timer.

I did also test the `system enable` way and that one actually did behave correctly. I enabled my `foo.timer`. Reboot the system. Timer was active and service wasn't immediately. When the `OnCondition` time came, the service ran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`systemd.timer(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html):

> If a timer configured with `OnBootSec=` or `OnStartupSec=` is already in the past when the timer unit is activated, it will immediately elapse and the configured unit is started. This is not the case for timers defined in the other directives.

Since your timer unit sets `OnBootSec=0min`, it will always start the service unit immediately.